# Excel VBA Macro: Iterating over values on one page to check for match on another page and assign value

Tags: vba, excel, assign

What I want to do: Iterate over values on one page to check for match on another page and if a match is found take a value from 2nd page same row but different column.

I've been trying now for quite some time. I'm new to VBA-scripting / Excel and might be approaching the problem incorrectly, hence why I'm asking here!

My code so far:

```
Sub InsertData()
ScreenUpdating = False


Dim wks As Worksheet

Dim subSheet As Worksheet
Set subSheet = Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim rowRangeSub As Range
Dim LastRowSub As Long
LastRowSub = subSheet.Cells(subSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set rowRangeSub = subSheet.Range("C2:C" & LastRowSub)
Dim subGroupList As ListObject


Dim rowRange As Range
Dim colRange As Range

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim Found As Range
'START OF SHEET1'
Set wks = Sheets("SHEET1")
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set rowRange = wks.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
'Loop through each row in B column (Names)'
For Each rrow In rowRange
    If Not IsEmpty(rrow) Then
        With Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C2:C" & LastRowSub)

            Set Found = .Find(What:=rrow, _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                'Debug.Print "Found"'
                wks.Cells(rrow.Row, "K").Value = "Found"
            Else
                wks.Cells(rrow.Row, "K").Value = "Not Found"

                'Debug.Print "Not Found"'
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next rrow

'END OF SHEET1'
'START OF SHEET2'
Set wks = Sheets("SHEET2")
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rowRange = wks.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

'END OF SHEET2'
'START OF SHEET3'
Set wks = Sheets("SHEET3")
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rowRange = wks.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

'END OF SHEET3'


ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The setup in the Excel file is as such:
The three sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 contains a lot of data in its 10 first columns (A-J) and the 11th column (K) is where the data is to be inserted if it is found. Pertinent data, names, is found in column B where B:1 is just "Name" as a title. There is also some empty cells in the column to take into consideration.

The 4th sheet, Sheet4 contains some data in its 5 first columns. The names which are to be matched can be found in column C, and if a match is found it is supposed to collect data from the Cells(Found.Row, "E") where "E" is column E.

This problem has been screwing with my head quite a lot since .Find()-function seems to not work as I expect it to, as in it finds the opposites sometimes.

My main question is: How do I assign the correct value to the row?

```
wks.Cells(rrow.Row, "K").Value = rowRangeSub.Cells(Found.Row, "E").Value
```

I feel like I've tested at least 10 different ways to assign, but I keep on getting error after error. Most of the time it's a missmatch error.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT since reading comments:
Ok, here it goes :
All columns are formatted as text.
Column A: Personal numbers: not relevant
Column B: Names: Form is: Lastname, Firstname. This is to be used when searching for a match.
Column C to J not relevant with various information about a person.
Column K: This columns cell starts out empty. This is to be filled by the macro.

I have three different books within the Excel file that have data that looks like what I've explained, just different data in each book.

The 4th book is as such:
Column A and B is not relevant with info not needed at all.

Column C: Is the names in form Lastname, Firstname. This is what should be the column cells to compare with column B's cells in the other books.

Column D: Not relevant

Column E: This is the important part of Sheet4. For every person there is a "group number" that can be found in this column for every row.

What I want to do is compare each cell in column B in Sheet1-3 for a match in column C in Sheet4. If a match is found (not all are assigned a group, so matches might not be found) then take cell information from Sheet4 on the row which a match was found and column "E", put this information in the row in Sheet1-3 and column "K".

Example data (is there a way to submit tables?):
**Sheet1:**

*COLUMN B*

Tablesson, Pen

Paper, Ink

Eraser, Screen

*COLUMN K* is at this moment empty

**Sheet4:**

*COLUMN C*

Paper, Ink

Eraser, Screen

*COLUMN E*

55

77

RUNS THE MACRO, **Sheet1** after macro:

*COLUMN B*

Tablesson, Pen

Paper, Ink

Eraser, Screen

*COLUMN K*

[First entry is empty since no match was found]

55

77

Hopefully this is understandable!

Comment: Can you post some representative data and an example of the goal?  It will help to clarify your needs

Comment: is it possible for your `Found.Row` to be greater than `lastRowSub`? That might cause an issue. I'm not sure if you can have a range, of like `Set rng = Range("A1:A10")` then `rng.Cells(11,1)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Post some representative data and an example of the goal. That will be very easy to understand.

Comment: Edited main post with more information

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, Found.Row could be greater than lastRowSub since there exists more data, hence more rows, in Sheet4 than each Sheet1,2,3 individually. Hmm, you're thinking about me using With Sheets(....... ? It's something I just tried from reading online basically. 

I think I might be lacking some fundamental Excel-VBA fact. Like why can't I just define the variables and use them as I've defined them, do you really have to only have one sheet active at a time etc?

Comment: I think I've found one problem. Basically even though the values in the different sheets looks exactly the same they aren't for some reason. I tested this with the manual Find-function. So now I'm looking into how to "clean" my values before comparing them. Any tips on that is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the process by using a Scripting Dictionary.

```js
Sub InsertData()
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim dicNames, k As String, v As Variant

    Set dicNames = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Create list of Names to compare against and values to update
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow
        
            k = .Cells(x, 3).Value  'Name from Column C
            v = .Cells(x, 5).Value  'Value From Column E

            'Add Key Value pairs to Dictionary
            If Not dicNames.Exists(k) Then dicNames.Add k, v
        Next
    End With

    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet1"), dicNames
    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet2"), dicNames
    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet3"), dicNames

End Sub

Sub ProcessWorksheet(ws As Worksheet, ByRef dicNames)
    Dim k As String, v As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow
            k = .Cells(x, 2)    'If Name from Column B
            If dicNames.Exists(k) Then
                .Cells(x, 11) = dicNames(k) 'Then Column K = Value from Sheet4
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Doing it this way seems very clean. Like I said before, I'm new to VBA so CreateObject("scripting.dictionary"), Variant, ByRef, amongst other things are completely new to me. 

I tried to run it, but I get "Subscript out of range" and pointing at "With Worksheet("Sheet4")", how come? I've changed the default name, but the post (Name) = Sheet4 is still there and should still work?

Also changed the code to take duplicates into account since that could happen I just noticed. Also added cleaning of cells for comparison since they were not the same value without it.

It works!

Comment: Look at the VBA Project Explorer displays the Object Code Name and it's property name for each Sheet e.g. Sheet1(Sheet4).  It is better to refer to the Worksheets by there code name. Sheet1.Range("A1") as opposed to WorkSheet("Sheet4").Range("A1")  because the later can be change by an end user.  Check and make sure the WorkSheet references are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Sub InsertData()
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim dicNames, k As String, v As Variant

    Set dicNames = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Create list of Names to compare against and values to update
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow
        
            k = .Cells(x, 3).Value  'Name from Column C
            v = .Cells(x, 5).Value  'Value From Column E

            'Add Key Value pairs to Dictionary
            If Not dicNames.Exists(k) Then dicNames.Add k, v
        Next
    End With

    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet1"), dicNames
    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet2"), dicNames
    ProcessWorksheet Worksheets("Sheet3"), dicNames

End Sub

Sub ProcessWorksheet(ws As Worksheet, ByRef dicNames)
    Dim k As String, v As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow
            k = .Cells(x, 2)    'If Name from Column B
            If dicNames.Exists(k) Then
                .Cells(x, 11) = dicNames(k) 'Then Column K = Value from Sheet4
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Basically used the code provided by Thomas Inzina with minor changes:

```
    If dicNames.Exists(k) Then
        newV = IIf(dicNames(k) = v, v, dicNames(k) & "," & v)
        dicNames.Remove (k)
        dicNames.Add k, newV
    Else
        dicNames.Add k, v
    End If
```

This takes duplicates into consideration.

I also used [this cleaning function](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/155-Trim-all-Cells-in-a-Worksheet-VBA#post1092) since I couldn't find the built-in one in VBA. Used them as such:

```
k = CleanTrim(.Cells(X, 3).Value)  'Name from Column C
k = CleanTrim(.Cells(X, 2).Value)  'If Name from Column B
```