# VBA code to use rather than vlookup

Tags: vba

I have two very large tables. One of them has 12 columns and 280K rows. The other ones has 12k rowns and 33 columns. I am using vlookup to look for matching values in large table to small one. Vlookups take forever to calculate. Is there an easy way to do this with a VBA code? Can someone share a sample code for me to replicate?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I havent tried anything yet. New to VBA and not sure if this is something that can be done.

Comment: It can be done. You can process all of the VLOOKUP (or Index/Match) within VBA (not a function on the worksheet). Does that help you get started?

Comment: You need to use a Scripting Dictionary.  Reference: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  My answer to  [Excel VBA Macro: Iterating over values on one page to check for match on another page and assign value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792580/excel-vba-macro-iterating-over-values-on-one-page-to-check-for-match-on-another/37806960#37806960) uses a dictionary to match key values between two lists, in order to update a value in the second list.

Comment: Have a look at `FIND`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collection` object to quickly find matches. This will work very fast (if not faster than `VLOOKUP`) because when you add key parameter to `Collection` - it hashes / indexes its value with the specific goal of fast lookup later).

Moreover, for the large number of records you populate `Collection` once and keep reusing it, while `VLOOKUP` does search the entire target range repeatedly (which is way less efficient, although built-in formulas run in parallel on multiple cores plus Microsoft definitely built-in some caching for increased efficiency for repeated searches). Even then a single-threaded VBA collections should still be faster.

See example below with more information in the in-line comments.

"Big Table" is on Sheet1:

[image: Big Table]

"Small Table" is on Sheet2:

[image: Small Table]

And the code that matches records in small table to those in the big one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub matchRows()

    ' this is where the big table is
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' this is where the small table is
    Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Set w2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim c As New Collection ' list of match keys in big table 1
    Dim r As Range

    ' assume the match key is in col1 in both tables
    ' enumerate the keys in the big table
    For Each r In w1.Range(w1.[a2], w1.[a2].End(xlDown))
        c.Add r, r ' this stores the range (first param) and
                    ' its key (second param - taken as string
                    ' (value of the range), must be unique)
    Next r

    ' now lets try to match / vlookup records in small table against
    ' big table
    For Each r In w2.Range(w2.[a2], w2.[a2].End(xlDown))
        If contains(c, CStr(r)) Then
            ' you didn't say what you want to do after a match, so
            ' I'll just display matched key value and row number in debug console
            Debug.Print "Found match """ & r & """ at row number " & r.Row
        Else
            Debug.Print "No match found for """ & r & """ at row number " & r.Row
        End If
    Next r

End Sub

Function contains(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    col.Item key
    contains = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Result in Immediate Window:

```
Found match "data51" at row number 2
Found match "data61" at row number 3
No match found for "data81" at row number 4
Found match "data91" at row number 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Is this something i need to copy to module?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you open immediate window `Ctrl-G`, put the cursor somewhere inside `matchRows()` and press `F5` to run.

Comment: When i run the code i am getting Compile error : Sub or Function not defined error message. I wonder whats causing it? Thanks

Comment: There is another helper function `contains()` below - make sure you copied that over as well (on my browser there is a scroll bar to scroll down the code - you may not have copied over everything).

Comment: Yes i did include helper function. but getting compile error; Method or Data Member not found error message. Thanks

Comment: Does it say / highlight which line? Also make sure you have "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" with the data as pictured above.

Comment: It highlights "Sub matchRows()" in yellow and put the cursor on book1

Comment: I change the workbook names now i am not getting an error message but vba code is not doing anything? Thanks

https://ufile.io/2b124

Comment: Hi Logan,  I tried it over and over again. when i run the code it puts the cursor on R in the middle of "(c, CStr(r))" and highlights Sub matchRows()
 in yelllow. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure what the issue is - it is probably can't locate the data in a second sheet properly. Here is the link to my spreadsheet that is working. If it runs ok on your machine, try replacing data (little by little) and see if you can make it work. https://ufile.io/11a19

Comment: Hi, I dont get an error message but the code doesnt return results

Comment: Results are in the "Immediate" window (aka console) - you can see it by pressing `Ctrl-G` or from the View menu. I've made remarks in my code as to where the actual match a happens. This is where you'd need to do what you planned originally for matches.

Comment: Great! Thank you for all your help Logan